# chmod 744 to my home dir, other user in same group can still not copy/cd my files

Tags: linux, bash

So my home dir is set as:

```sh
drwxr--r--  16 me  users  4096 Jan 15 09:17 me
```

I want to copy my files from using admin user which belongs to the same group(users):

```sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 otickadm users 4096 Jan 15 08:59 common
```

However I can't:

```sh
$ cd /jhome/jyun1
-bash: cd: /jhome/jyun1: Permission denied

$ cp /jhome/jyun1/gitworkspace/taq_scripts/sanity_check.py .
cp: cannot stat ‘/jhome/jyun1/gitworkspace/taq_scripts/sanity_check.py’: Permission denied
```

Wondering if anything else is taking control of this permission.

Comment: Even group doesn't have the write permissions, so IMHO that is why it is not able to write the files.

Comment: @markp, nice! this way it works now -Thank you! if you answer it below, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd` (and read files) requires execute (`x`) perms on the **directory**; try `75x` to allow others in your group to `cd` to your directory and/or read your files